# IF ELIF ELSE Conditional met using input

Tags: python, if-statement

To summaries I am making a basic tde calculator and I want the user to input how active they are per week
The problem I am having is after typing how active the user is I want the condition to end but the input functions still stay open. I've tried defining "input()" but it still doesnt work.

Here is an example code
Try typing in lightly active and youll see the input still stays open instead of exiting the condition

```
if input() == "sedentary":
 print(5 * 1.2)
elif input() == "lightly active":
 print (5 * 1.6)
else: 
input()
print ("not recognized")
```

Comment: For every single `input()`, Python will again ask for input. You probably only want to ask once?! `v = input(); if v == ...: ... elif v == ...: ...`

Comment: You are taking a total of 3 input()s ... take it once in front and store it inside a variable. Beside that you got an IndentationError to fix. You might want to use 4 spaces as laid out in PEP-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting new input in the `if/elif/else` sections, just get it once, assign to a variable and compare that

```
user_input = input()
if user_input  == "sedentary":
     print(5 * 1.2)
elif user_input  == "lightly active":
     print (5 * 1.6)
else:     
     print ("not recognized")
```